# SSRS Report Builder - Display All Summarized Rows From One Table and Associated Data Rows

Tags: reporting-services, report, builder

I am still learning the ropes of report builder and was curious what approach one would take to display a calculated parent table and all the child dependencies (rows) that went into the calculations for the parent row entry.

I already have triggers calculating values from multiple rows in one table that share a key value which is summarizing the mean/std dev etc from all these rows, thus placing the calculated results into a single row in the parent table.

I want to select multiple rows from the calculated (parent) table and show it in a report, then
show all the rows that went into the parents calculations. I can do this in sql because it is just a reverse lookup on the key value from both tables, but i am not sure how to dynamically do this in report builder. Any advice would be appreciated.

Here is a very simplified example of the child table that is used for the calculations
[Child Data Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HTPQ.png)

Here is a very simplified example of the summation parent table

[Parent Calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O2iV.png)

This is similar to what I am looking to do in report builder

[Parent To Child Report Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51Ii8.png)

Any advice on process/approach/what tool to use would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is the parent and child data in separate dataset or same dataset?

Comment: Currently they are in separate datasets.

Comment: Is there a reason why they are in separate datasets and not a single dataset?

Comment: no real reason why they are separate, i can combine as long as there is no real performance impact of joining potentially a couple hundred thousand rows with a smaller rowset. Would combining and using a matrix make make things easier?

Comment: it sure would be.. performance shouldn't be an issue.. you are running two sets of code now.. combining it will - theoretically should make the report faster as you are retrieving data only once